# How to deserialize an object's property with a specific derived class

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

I need Asp.net to deserialize an object's property with a specific derived class.

According to Newtonsoft's documentation, I should be able to change the JsonContract for the base class Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard.
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm

Class Transmitter has a property (Simcard) *Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard*, but I need to have it deserialized as *TlsModel.SimCard*, otherwise *TlsModel.SimCard* properties are discarded during deserialization.

```
public class TlsModelContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (objectType == typeof(Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard) )
        {
            contract.CreatedType = typeof(SimCard);
            Console.WriteLine("Simcard CreateType is updated");

        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

At the first deserialization, I have the log line 'Simcard CreateType is updated', so my contract deseralizer is taken into account.

But transmitter.SimCard is still a *Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard* and not *TlsModel.SimCard* as I excptected.

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3):

You must also replace the value of [`JsonContract.DefaultCreator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreator.htm) with an appropriate creation function, and possibly set [`JsonContract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_DefaultCreatorNonPublic.htm) if the base class did not have a public constructor:

```
public class TlsModelContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        JsonContract contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (objectType == typeof(Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard) )
        {
            contract.CreatedType = typeof(SimCard);
            Debug.WriteLine("Simcard CreateType is updated");
            contract.DefaultCreator = () => new SimCard();
            contract.DefaultCreatorNonPublic = false;
        }

        return contract;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- After calling the base method [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateContract.htm) the contract is fully initialized so you will need to make any and all changes manually.
- If your `SimCard` model has a parameterized constructor you will need to override [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateObjectContract.htm) and update the [`CreatorParameters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_CreatorParameters.htm) and [`OverrideCreator`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_OverrideCreator.htm).
- As an alternative to a custom contract resolver you could have introduced a [`SimCardConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomCreationConverter.htm) whose [`Create()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_CustomCreationConverter_1_Create.htm) method returns a `new SimCard()`.

  ```cs
  public class SimCardConverter : CustomCreationConverter<Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard>
  {
      public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return typeof(Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard) == objectType; }

      public override Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard Create(Type objectType) { return new SimCard(); }
  }
  ```

  (You might also need to override [`CustomCreationConverter<T>.CanConvert(Type objectType)`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/CustomCreationConverter.cs#L88) to return `typeof(T) == objectType;` rather than `typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);` if you ever directly deserialize any derived types of `Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard`.)

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YQ6WiE).

Comment: I have an issue with the Resolver solution: properties on the derived class are not deserialized although the correct type is created. I updated the fiddle you created here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Vi1s to add a property SerialNumber on the derived class. Please can you just run it to see what happens ?

Comment: @AnthonyBrenelière - it might be better to ask another question with a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, I would think. Your original question from six weeks ago seemed to be about *object construction* so that's what the answer covered.  You might check to see whether  `CustomCreationConverter<Equipment.Shared.Model.SimCard>` from the fiddle above coincidentally solves the problem.  Or at least edit the current question to clarify your requirement.

Comment: My question never changed and is about deserialization of objects that have properties on derived class and on base class. With the resolver's solution, the correct type is well created with DefaultCreator added, but what's the point if its properties are not deserialized ? 
Did you run the fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/d5Vi1s ? It shows it works with a Converter but not with the Resolver solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using newtonsoft json you can do it by using (at serialization and deserialization type) the Type Name Handling as explained here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm

It just adds the property "@type" to each object.

Example

Consider the following class:

```
//dll My.Dll
namespace My.Namespace
public class MyObj {
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public object Whatever {get;set;}
}

var objInner = new MyObj { Name = "Inner" };
var objOuter = new MyObj { Name = "Outer", Whatever = obj1 }

var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objOuter, Formatting.Indented, new 
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
Console.Writeline(jsonString);

//produces
//{
//  "@type": "My.Namespace.MyObj, My.Dll",
//  "Name":  "Outer",
//  "Whatever": {
//       "@type": "My.Namespace.MyObj, My.Dll",
//       "Name": "Inner"
//   }
//}

//to deserialize
var deserializedObj = JsonConvert.DserializeObject<MyObj>(objOuter, new 
JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});
```

Comment: The json is serialized by the API client that has no idea of the type used for deserilization. I cannot make the client dependent of the date model , type and assembly names used in the code.